# Node.js http.request is not working with subdomain?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make remote request call inside **Node.js**. But when I did, it gives me error below in Terminal.

```
BODY: <html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code.

```
var jsonObject = JSON.stringify(jsonData);

// HTTP Call - POST
var options = {
    host: 'subdomain.example.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/api/logs',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'api_key' : config.systemApikey,
        'secret_key' : config.systemSecretkey
    }
};

// do the POST call
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + data);
        });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});

req.write(jsonObject);
req.end();
```

If I try the host with local network like `192.168.0.2` with port `5000` (which I assign to use for that another application), it is working. I am new to *Node.js*, and please help me with what I did wrong here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

host should be a string

```
var options = {
    host: 'subdomain.example.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/api/logs',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'api_key' : config.systemApikey,
        'secret_key' : config.systemSecretkey
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It is in string and I wrongly removed *quotes* while posted here :)

Comment: OK, well, it looks fine to me. I tried a GET request to `http://ci.societypro.org:8080` with your code (and no headers) and it returns the page as expected. The fact that you get the HTML means the request also worked. You've asked the server for something bad, though, or the server is broken.